# Intermittent crash after UIImagePickerController with camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

We have an app that is working stable, but occasionally users report that they get crashes when they use the function to take a picture with the camera.

The problem is that the crash seems to happen just when `UIImagePickerController` is closed and the control is returned to the app.

We set the delegate when the pickerController is loaded

```
- (IBAction)popupShootPhoto:(id)sender {
    // Detect if camera is available, otherwise exit
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        return;
    }

    UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    pickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When the app resumes, the photo is normally processed in the callback to the regular delegate method.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

The problem is that we cannot reproduce the problem. All we have to work from are the crash logs that we have available in the organizer from the devices.

This is what the crashing thread typically look like, there are no references to our own code, so we have not much to work from.

[image]

Can anyone suggest an approach to resolve or troubleshoot problems like this? The problem has been the same on both iOS 9 and still exists on iOS 10.

Comment: What class is your `popupShootPhoto:` method in?

Comment: The metod is in a regular subclassed UIViewController, nothing strange about it at all. What complicates things is that it works good 99,9% of the times, but on rare occations the app crashes without any traces to work from. We have still not been able to reproduce it ourselves.  We have also tried to add the Twitter Crashlytics framework, but nothing is reported there either.